# Auth0 migrating from lock widget to auth0-js: How to customize look and feel

Tags: auth0

My angular app uses auth0 for authentication. Earlier, it used the lock widget to show the login dialog. Now I am migrating to auth0-js, as specified in [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/04-authorization) guide.

Earlier, I could customize the lock widget and provide my own logo and theme color by following parameters.

```
theme: {
    logo: 'assets/images/mylogo.png',
    primaryColor: '#0275d8'
},
```

But, I cannot find anything similar in `auth0-js`.

Is there any way I can provide a custom log to the login screen?

Comment: Hi, did the answer below help?

Comment: I understand the question and not sure the accepted answer covers it.  When you call the authorize function in auth0.js, it redirects the user to almost exactly the same screen as lock.js puts up (but without ability to customise).  I don't feel the answers on the auth0 site are that conclusive either.  On the help page it recommends using lock for SPA, but if you click on their SPA quickstarts lock is not to be found.

Comment: Are you using Universal Login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Auth0.js** - Client Side Javascript toolkit for Auth0 API access.

https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js

You can think of auth0.js as "headless". It does not offer any look & feel customization, instead you integrate it with whatever custom UI solution you are using.

**Lock** - Authentication broker that supports authentication via username / password, social as well as enterprise identity providers.

https://github.com/auth0/lock

Lock offers a UI "widget" right out of the box, and then allows you to add settings that customize that UI (login, signup, forgot password, additional connnection types etc)

So your decision is really **Lock vs. Custom UI** - the Auth0 docs offer some good advice here to help you make the right decision.

https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/when-to-use-lock